# What's the newer version or the alternative to Cuda Occupancy Calculator?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm working with a Tesla P100 having compute capability 6.0.
I'd like to find a tool to automatically get the best grid and block sizes w.r.t. my kernel code.

I recently discovered the **CUDA Occupancy Calculator** (the .xls spreadsheet). But I realized it's a bit outdated (the Capability was until 2.1).

- I tried to search for a newer spreadsheet, including higher C.C., but nothing showed up.
- So I searched for an alternative and I found that from CUDA 6.5 on, [Occupancy APIs](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-occupancy-api-simplifies-launch-configuration/) were introduced.
  Is this the newer alternative to the spreadsheet?
- Furthermore, I found this [tool](https://xmartlabs.github.io/cuda-calculator/)
  from GitHub.
  Can I consider this as an alternative? Or is it better to use Occupancy APIs?

Also, can CUDA profilers (**nvprof** or **Nsight**) do estimations about occupancy and give some optimal block/grid size?

I'm a quite new about these tools.

Comment: An updated version of the occupancy calculator ships in every CUDA toolkit. If you have the toolkit installed, you have the spreadsheet. Look under tools in the CUDA install directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An updated version of the CUDA occupancy calculator spreadsheet ships with the CUDA toolkit, so when you install the CUDA toolkit, the excel spreadsheet is also installed on your machine.  Maybe easiest just to use a file find utility for your OS to find it.

The [CUDA occupancy API](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-occupancy-api-simplifies-launch-configuration/) allows you to make the same calculations at runtime.

NVIDIA profilers offer some capability to inspect achieved occupancy.  For example, [nvvp](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#details-view) can display achieved occupancy,  and there is a [metric for achieved occupancy](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference) which you can gather with nvprof.  You may wish to simply search [the profiler docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html) for the word "occupancy".  These tools don't make estimations of optimal block and grid sizes, but they may give an indication as to whether occupancy may be a performance limiter for your application.  These tools can also report the actual block and grid sizes for each kernel launch.

Comment: For me the best solution is using CUDA occupancy API. This is because I work with a remote server where LibreOffice isn't installed (I've no admin privileges). Then I'm not able to open occupancy spreadsheet, even though I found that under tools folder in CUDA toolkit.

Comment: you can copy the occupancy calculator spreadsheet to your own laptop and use it there.  It doesn't require any other parts of the CUDA toolkit.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very complete tool that help you find best configuration
Check my configuration and the graphs
You want the red dots to be on the peak of each graph

You can check it out https://xmartlabs.github.io/cuda-calculator/